# How to take I/O in Greek, in C program on Windows console

Tags: c, unicode, io, internationalization

For a school project I decided to make an app. I am writing it in C, and running it on the Windows Console. I live in Greece and the program needs read and write text in Greek too. So, I have tried just plainly

```
printf("Καλησπέρα");
```

But it prints some random characters. How can I output Greek letters? And, similarly, how can I take input in Greek?

Comment: Look at this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=msvc-170#example-use-_setmode-to-change-stdout

Comment: Your example `printf("Καλησπέρα");` will work *if* your C compiler and your display environment agree on which encoding — UTF-8, UTF-16, etc. — to use for the Unicode characters.  You might also need to add the lines `#include <locale.h>` and `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");` to your program.  See also http://utf8everywhere.org/ .

Comment: @Steve Summit thanks. I will try it when I am able

Comment: I implemented the solution proposed in the book *Modern C*, similar to the one proposed by @Steve. It works in my Linux environment, not in my Winndows one ...

Comment: @Damien ok. What do you propose

Comment: The book proposes `setlocale (LC_ALL, "");`. But the behavior is the same as with Steve's variant.

Comment: On Windows, when you use C Runtime to print text in Unicode, you should switch the output mode to Unicode by calling `_setmode` with the first parameter set to the file descriptor of sdtout and the second parameter set to _O_U16TEXT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for asking such an interesting question! I wish what you are trying to do was simple. But your programming language (C), and your execution environment (the Windows console) were both designed a long time ago, without Greek in mind. As a result, it is not easy to use them for your simple school project.

When your C program outputs bytes to stdout via printf, the Windows Console interprets those bytes as characters. It has a default interpretation, or *encoding*, which does not include Greek. In order for your Greek letters to appear, you need to tell Windows Console to use the correct encoding. You do this using the `_setmode` call, using the `_O_U16TEXT` parameter. This is described in the [Windows _setmode documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=msvc-170#example-use-_setmode-to-change-stdout), as Semih Artan pointed out in the comments.

The `_O_U16TEXT` mode means your program must print text out in UTF-16 form. Each character is 16 bits long. That means you must represent your text as wide characters, using C syntax like `L"\x039a"`. The `L` before the double quotes marks the string as having "wide characters", where each character has 16 bits instead of 8 bits. The `\x` in the string indicates that the next four characters are hex digits, representing the 16 bits of a wide character.

Your C program is itself a text file. The C compiler must interpret the bytes of this text file in terms of characters. When used in a simple way, the compiler will expect only ASCII-compatible byte values in the file. That includes Latin letters and digits, and simple punctuation. It does not include Greek letters. Thus you must write your Greek text by representing its bytes with ASCII substitutes.

There Greek characters `Καλησπέρα` are, I believe, represented in C wide character syntax as `L"\x039a\x03b1\x03bb\x03b7\x03c3\x03c0\x03ad\x03c1\x03b1"`.

Finally, Windows Console must have access to a Greek font in order for it to display the Greek characters. I expect this is not a problem for you, because you are probably already running your computer in Greek. In any case Windows worldwide includes fonts with Greek coverage.

Plugging this Greek text into the sample program in Microsoft's `_setmode` documentation gives this. (Note: I have not tested this program myself.)

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wprintf(L"\x039a\x03b1\x03bb\x03b7\x03c3\x03c0\x03ad\x03c1\x03b1\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Input is another matter. I won't attempt to go through it here. You probably have to set the mode of **stdin** to `_O_U16TEXT`. Then characters will appear as UTF-16. You may need to convert them before they are useful to your program.

Overall, to write a simple app for a school project, which reads and writes Greek, I suggest that you consider using a tool like Visual Studio to write a GUI program. These tools have more modern design, and give you access to text with Greek letters more easily.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think that I will be just fine using _setmode BUT 2 questions:

1. Do I NEED to implement the text as ASCII chars? It will be somewhat tough and will take some time and 

2. I would LOVE to use VS but I only know some basic C and VS doesn't (sadly) support C... or does it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Q: "Do I NEED to implement the text as ASCII chars?" A: Yes. As I said in the answer, "…the compiler will expect only ASCII-compatible byte values in the file.… Thus you must write your Greek text by representing its bytes with ASCII substitutes."

Comment: Q: "VS doesn't (sadly) support C... or does it?" A: that is a different question. It looks like you are new to Stack Overflow. One thing to learn about it is that these comments are not for discussions and follow-up questions. Ask your question about Visual Studio as a separate question, and let it get separate answers. The knowledge is clearer and easier to find that way. Plus, you get more reputation points. I will not try to answer the follow-up question in this discussion.

Comment: Another tip for success at Stack Overflow: if this is the correct answer to your question, then please click on the "check" mark (✔️) to the left of the answer to accept it. If this answer is helpful, click the upwards triangle to give it a vote. Upvoting and accepting helpful answers makes them more visible to other readers. (It also give me, as the answer writer, more points.)

Comment: Yeah... I am new... I know that "it takes an eye out" (it means it is obvious) as we say here in Greece! Anyway thank you for your answers!